# If there was no Earth, what would be the acceleration of gravity from here from the Sun?

Tags: gravity, astronomy, acceleration, sun

Suppose there were no Earth to pull us back and we're hanging in the solar system. Assuming no other force of gravity from other bodies, what would be the $g$ from the Sun?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can get this from Newton's law of gravitation: the acceleration due to gravity is then
$$
g=\frac Fm =G\frac{mM_\odot }{mr^2}=\frac{GM_\odot}{r^2},
$$
which [comes out](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28newton%27s+constant%29%2asolar+mass%2F%28orbital+radius+of+earth%29%5E2) to about 5 mm/s$^2$. This is of course the orbital acceleration of Earth.

Comment: Would that orbital acceleration be the speed that one object travels along the orbital? How fast an object( typical human) travels along that orbital if $ g= 5 mm/s^2$?

Comment: You're confusing [speed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speed) and [acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration). (!). The orbital speed of Earth is about 30 km/s. Anything at Earth's position with an orbital speed smaller than that would go much closer to the Sun; below 3 km/s you're likely to crash into it.